# What is the source of this (?) hymn? What does it mean?

Tags: identification-request, hymn

I saw a WhatsApp forward about an "extremely difficult poem". It sounded like a hymn to me. My transliteration from the original Malayalam:

> nrtyadhUrjjaTi karagataDamarukaDumuDumupaTuravaparipanthinyah
>
> kalpakshmAruha vikasitakusumajama dhurasamadhurimasahacaariNya
>
> manthakshmAdharavimathitajalanidhighumughumugha naravamadamanthinyah
>
> shailAbdhIshwara nrpvara! vidadhatu budhasukhamayi tava vacasam shreNyah.

Is this from a *smriti* or Hindu text? What does it mean? How, and on what occasion, does one chant it?

Comment: According to [this](http://malayalam.usvishakh.net/blog/archives/293) blog, it looks like a poem written by Uddanda Shastri. Maybe you can translate the meaning from the blog to English and write your own answer.

Comment: The blog allows to translate into English.  So meaning of the sloka can be obtained by opting for translation.  However, the OP is asking for occasion in which this sloka will be chanted.  This will be known to people, who knows Malayalam literature. @sv.

Comment: 'blog allows to translate into English' - I know and I already did, but Google translate isn't accurate for Indian languages yet. I thought OP can provide a better translation. It's just a Sanskrit poem, I don't think it will be chanted during a special occasion, so technically, the question is off-topic for the site. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: @sv.:Perhaps, yes

Comment: @s.v., thank you, I am about to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because translating is not a topic of this forum.

Comment: Wow this is such a beautiful verse and enchanting poetic meter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sincere thanks to [sv.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/2995/sv), who pointed out a [useful blog post](http://malayalam.usvishakh.net/blog/archives/293).

This appears to have been written by a Malabari Sanskrit scholar, *Uddandasastrikal*, who was infamous for his difficult, wordy compositions. He was one of the court poets of the Zamorin (*samUtiri)* of Kozhikode, *Manavikraman*. The meaning of the composition in the post:

> O, Lord of the mountain in the ocean (*shailabdhIshwara*, *shiva*), O King (*nrpvara*),
>   whose voice is like the "dumudumu" sound of his *damaru*, whose sweetness
>   is comparable to that of the nectar of the heavenly wish-granting tree (*kalpavrksha*),
>   who destroys the ego of those with the "ghumughumu" voice like the clarification (*manthana*) of the *Mandara* sea, may the order of your words bring pleasure to *pandit*s.

It seems to be a simple poem, rather than a hymn or invocation. It could possibly be chanted during a Malayali-style *namajapam* (though I doubt anyone would do that, given the difficulty!), or even be set to music as a *bhajana*.